What is the correct topology for a a 5 edge extrusion pole on a Assault Rifle Barrel?

I am making a high poly assault rifle for a FPS game in Unreal Engine 5, then I will bake the textures on a low poly model
As you can see in the first image there is this 5 pole.
The second image is where I moved the pole to a flat surface, I want to do the same for the pole in the first image but its really confusing.

Last picture is my model


“Pole”? What is a pole in this context?

@TheLabCat In mesh topology "poles" are usually vertices where 5 or more edges meet. Often vertices where only 3 edges meet are called poles as well. Basically every vertex with a number of edges not equal to 4, with the ones having 5 being called E-poles and those having 3 are N-poles.

You would be able to not have it there by selecting this whole face and doing Alt+E->'Extrude Manifold' and moving it down

I'm not sure you actually need to do his tho. If you give it a Bevel modifier with 2 segments the 5 edge vertex will turn to quads anyways

Also, if you want it to look exactly like the top row, what you need to do is select all the side faces and extrude them once. Then extrude the alternating ones to make the 'teeth'

there's still a 5 pole though in the middle of the corner?

I need the pole moved to a flat surface, not at a corner, unless 5 poles are allowed???

@AdamShakeel 5 poles are sometimes just unavoidable. Is it actually causing issues for you? If you want it on a flat surface just do the same thing as you did on the top. Extrude all the side faces and then extrude the alternating ones afterwards
